# CASE error with certain values in some params

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, errors

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UTILS_CITYVALUES_GET_LIST]
 @IndexId BIGINT = -1
,@PageSize INT = 15
,@Ascending BIT = '1'
,@SortAttribute NVARCHAR(20) = N'Municipality'
,@Country NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
,@CountryCode NVARCHAR(12)  = NULL
,@State NVARCHAR(70) = NULL
,@Zip NVARCHAR(16) = NULL
,@Municipality NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
,@Neighborhood NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
,@NeighborhoodType NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
,@City NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
,@CityPhoneCode NVARCHAR(12) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF @Ascending = '1' -- This case is to get ASC values
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP(@PageSize) *
        FROM  [dbo].[UTILS_CityValues] WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE   (@Country IS NULL OR [Country] = @Country)
            AND (@CountryCode IS NULL OR [CountryCode] = @CountryCode)
            AND (@State IS NULL OR [State] = @State)
            AND (@Zip IS NULL OR [Zip] = @Zip)
            AND (@Municipality IS NULL OR [Municipality] = @Municipality)
            AND (@Neighborhood IS NULL OR [Neighborhood] = @Neighborhood)
            AND (@NeighborhoodType IS NULL OR [NeighborhoodType] = @NeighborhoodType)
            AND (@City IS NULL OR [City] = @City)
            AND (@CityPhoneCode IS NULL OR [CityPhoneCode] = @CityPhoneCode)
            AND [Id] > @IndexId
        ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Country' THEN [Country]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'CountryCode' THEN [CountryCode]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'State' THEN [State]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Zip' THEN [Zip]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Municipality' THEN [Municipality]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Neighborhood' THEN [Neighborhood]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'NeighborhoodType' THEN [NeighborhoodType]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'City' THEN [City]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'CityPhoneCode' THEN [CityPhoneCode]
                    ELSE [Id]
                END ASC;
    END
ELSE -- This case is to get DESC Values
    BEGIN
        -- Setting Id as max value in case 
        SET @IndexId = CASE 
            WHEN @IndexId < 0 THEN 999999999 
            ELSE @IndexId END;

        SELECT TOP(@PageSize) *
        FROM  [dbo].[UTILS_CityValues] WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE  (@Country IS NULL OR [Country] = @Country)
            AND (@CountryCode IS NULL OR [CountryCode] = @CountryCode)
            AND (@State IS NULL OR [State] = @State)
            AND (@Zip IS NULL OR [Zip] = @Zip)
            AND (@Municipality IS NULL OR [Municipality] = @Municipality)
            AND (@Neighborhood IS NULL OR [Neighborhood] = @Neighborhood)
            AND (@NeighborhoodType IS NULL OR [NeighborhoodType] = @NeighborhoodType)
            AND (@City IS NULL OR [City] = @City)
            AND (@CityPhoneCode IS NULL OR [CityPhoneCode] = @CityPhoneCode)
            AND [Id] < @IndexId
        ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Country' THEN [Country]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'CountryCode' THEN [CountryCode]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'State' THEN [State]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Zip' THEN [Zip]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Municipality' THEN [Municipality]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Neighborhood' THEN [Neighborhood]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'NeighborhoodType' THEN [NeighborhoodType]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'City' THEN [City]
                    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'CityPhoneCode' THEN [CityPhoneCode]
                    ELSE [Id]
                END DESC;
        END
END
```

When I execute this:

```
[dbo].[UTILS_CITYVALUES_GET_LIST] -1, 10, '1', 'City', NULL, NULL, 'Zacatecas', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

The compiler tell me this:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

But if I use 'Zip' instead of city it works, and the same applies for 'CityPhoneCode' and 'Municipality'.

Any clues on what is wrong?

Comment: See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by and http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing column types. Your CASE expression wants to produce something with a particular type, and in your case is trying to convert everything to bigint.

I think your best option is to seperate each column out, by inserting lots of `END, CASE` lines. Like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'State' THEN [State]
END, CASE
    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Zip' THEN [Zip]
END, CASE
    WHEN @SortAttribute = N'Municipality' THEN [Municipality]
END, CASE
    WHEN ...
```

Comment: This work fine even when using commas looks weird but when performing results are correct Thx!

Comment: Well, I'd recommend putting a line break between the comma and each new `CASE`, but the idea is to have each one separate.